# jquerymobile - drop-down links not working? Disabled it?

Tags: jquery, mobile, hyperlink

I'm using jquerymobile solely for its 'vmousedown' and 'taphold' functionality. Now, whenever I have a multi-level CSS drop-down menu, some of the links in the drop-down doesn't work on an iPad.

Whenever I click on it, it got a "#". I even tried putting 'rel="external"' and/or data-ajax="false" in my link, but that still doesn't solve the problem.

Is there a way to modify jquerymobile such that I use the 'vclick','vmouseodown', 'taphold' or any touch screen functionalities only? I don't need how jquerymobile processed links.

Comment: use "live" instead of "bind", and vclick is fine I think.

Comment: Actually, my main problem is getting my drop-down menu links to work in jquerymobile.

Comment: well can you share some of your codes here? so some one can check it.